# Row and column integer error when calling load

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I have a simple spreadsheet in Excel 97-2003 format, extension is XLS, that is throwing the following error when trying to load it with PHPSpreadSheet.

> Error 0 on line 49 in \PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\CellAddress.php -> Row and Column Ids must be positive integer values

The spreadsheet has 14 columns with no formulas or external references. Similar spreadsheets in the same format load and process without error.

```
require 'PHPSpreadsheet/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputfile);  // <-- this is where the failure happens
```

If I create a new spreadsheet and copy the rows from the one that fails into the new one the load works just fine. The header row and 1 row of data are shown below. I have tried removing the header row and manually entering a single row but get the same failure.

It seems to be related to the file itself but the error message isn't helping to determine exactly what the problem is.

```
DATE    Course ID   Title of Class  StartTime   PGH Location    Address City    State   Zip Code    Sponsor/Vendor  Instructor if Known Contact Information Telephone
1/10/2023   7280801 Dual Credit Water & Wastewater Workshop 08:00   6   Anywhere Fire Department    123 Main St Any Town    NC  28580   NC Statewide Safety Conference, Inc.    Sam Smith   Joe Smith   252-555-1212
```

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a bug in PHPSpreadsheet that was revealed by having a vertical break in row H0 for some reason.

Removing the breaks in the spreadsheet manually would also correct the problem but the latest version of PHPSpreadsheet has been fixed so it will not thrown an error if there is a vertical break in the first row.